Where to put extensions in YugabyteDB?
I'm just starting testing yugabyte using the yugabyted script.  Trying to see if it can replace our current postgresql implementation.  The server is running RHEL 8 Linux. I'm getting an error when trying to load a custom function.  Any advice would be appreciated.
The shared object named in the CREATE FUNCTION statement seems to be found, but the error message complains that a library it depends on (libmcpdb.so.1) cannot be found.  However that library is in the correct directory and is present in the ldconfig cache.  The function loads without a problem in postgresql.
# ./bin/ysqlsh -p5432 pcm_production
ysqlsh (11.2-YB-2.19.0.0-b0)
Type "help" for help.

pcm_production=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pcm_match_encrypt_str( TEXT, TEXT )
pcm_production-# RETURNS BOOLEAN
pcm_production-# AS '/usr/lib/libpcmdbcrypt.so.1.0', 'pcm_match_encrypt_str'
pcm_production-# LANGUAGE C
pcm_production-# IMMUTABLE;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/libpcmdbcrypt.so.1.0": libpcmdb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pcm_production=# \q

# ldd /usr/lib/libpcmdbcrypt.so.1.0
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd5bfe0000)
        libpq.so.5 => /lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fd34abb1000)
        libpcmdb.so.1 => /lib/libpcmdb.so.1 (0x00007fd34a94e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd34a58b000)

# ls -l /lib/libpcmdb*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  14480 Aug  8 14:22 /lib/libpcmdbcrypt.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     24 Oct  9  2020 /lib/libpcmdb.so -> /usr/lib/libpcmdb.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     24 Oct  9  2020 /lib/libpcmdb.so.1 -> /usr/lib/libpcmdb.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 759432 Oct  5  2020 /lib/libpcmdb.so.1.0

# ldconfig -p | grep libpcmdb
        libpcmdbcrypt.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libpcmdbcrypt.so.1.0
        libpcmdb.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libpcmdb.so.1
        libpcmdb.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libpcmdb.so


For extensions, PostgreSQL expects the .so files to be under its own directory and not on the system library path.
For refernec you can see https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/explore/ysql-language-features/pg-extensions/#pgsql-postal-example for steps for setting up custom plugin
In this case, just put the .so file in the directory $(yugabyte/postgres/bin/pg_config --pkglibdir). Additionally if there are .control and  .sql files should be copied to directory$(yugabyte/postgres/bin/pg_config --sharedir)/extension.
